# Linq Group By Sum based on a condition

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have this SQL query but can't figure out how to convert it into VB.net LINQ

```
SELECT 
    clientid, 
    SUM(IF(`type` = 1, cost, 0)) AS advexp,  
    SUM(IF(`type` = 3, cost, 0)) AS genexp 
FROM customerlist 
WHERE clGroupId=pGroupId 
GROUP BY clientid;
```

Table `customerlist` includes a field `type` and a field `cost`.  The intent is to get a total of type 1 and type 3 expenses in one query.

This is what I tried:

```
From p In db.customerlist
Where p.clGroupId=1 
Group By p.clientid,p.type Into g 
Select New With { .clientid=g.clientd,.advexp=g.Sum(Function(c) If(c.type=1, cost,0)),.genexp=g.Sum(Function(c) If(c.type=3, cost,0))}
```

But not able to compile.  The query is intended to hit the database.  The error is  `Definition of method 'g' is not accessible in this context`.

Comment: Those two LINQ queries are invalid. Are you using an ORM or trying to group a List in memory? Replicating the original query when working in memory is easy and almost the same as the SQL query

Comment: Group by multiple columns: `customerList.Where(c => c.GroupId == groupId).GroupBy(c => new { c.ClientId, c.Type }).Select(g => new { Group = g.Key, Total = g.Count * cost })`

Comment: The two queries work fine.  I skipped `db.customerlist` and `.tolist`.

Comment: @AllenKing the two LINQ queries are invalied. You can't write `into genexp=sum(cost), `

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I removed the example queries but they do work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't explain whether an ORM is used or what `customerlist` is. A list of customers in memory, or a DbSet ?

If this was a List, the LINQ query would be almost identical to the SQL query :

```
from customer in customerlist
where p.clGroupId=pGroupId 
group by p.clientid into g
select new { clientid=g.Key,
             advexp=g.Sum(c=>c.type==1?cost:0),
             genexp=g.Sum(c=>c.type==3?cost:0)
}
```

Depending on the ORM and the database provider used, EF or NHibernate may be able to translate the same query into SQL